# Passing data from Ajax to PHP, getting syntax error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having an error with some Ajax and PHP.

In the browser console I'm getting this message: The following error occured: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. I can't seem to figure out where this is coming from, and have tried debugging it as much as I can.

In main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".post").click(function(){
        var number = {event_number: this.id}; //This gets the ID of the element clicked
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache:false
        });
        request = $.ajax ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "event_page.php",
            data: number,
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        request.done(function(response){
            var resultsArray = response;
            console.log(resultsArray);
            $("#main").text(resultsArray);
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus,     errorThrown);
        });
    });
});
```

In event_page.php:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']), true);
    $event_number = $data['event_number'];
    echo $event_number;
?>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the full error message shown in the console:

```
The following error occured: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Object.parse (native)
at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js:4:16756)
at Xb (http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js:4:19069)
at y (http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js:4:22515)
at XMLHttpRequest.c (http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js:4:26989)
```

I would also like to point out that main.js and event_page.php exist in the same directory.

As you can see here, all I'm trying to do is send the element's ID to the PHP file, and I'm echoing it to verify that it had been sent. However, I'm getting the error above and I'm not too sure why this is happening.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `print_r($data);` please. I think it's $data[0]['event_number']

Comment: try using `data.response` in done change `var resultsArray = response;`

Comment: @aldrin27 - I tried that, and nothing happened, I'm still getting the error message. Something is triggering it before the PHP file is accessed?

Comment: Can you show what are the data's inside your `$data`?

Comment: You can look at your browser console to see the response from server including PHP error to help you, but your value is in `$_GET['event_number']` and not `$_GET['data']['event_number']`.

Comment: @aldrin27 - The data that is sent at any time is a whole number (0, 1, 2 or 45, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `event_number` to server using ajax

You can get it like this

```
$_GET['event_number'];
```

To get send back response as JSON try this:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($_GET['event_number']);
```

Comment: I have tried this but I'm still getting the exact same error message.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not even using it in main.js, it says it's in the jQuery .js file.

Comment: Where you wrote this in your code? If you don't know create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with code you are using;

Comment: Well it seemed I made an error in the naming on my end. The variable name in the $_GET['x'] has to match the variable name in the json {x : 1}. Thanks a lot for the help.